# ¿Cómo se cambia la URL (permalink) de un post en Wordpress 5.0?

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress 5.0 cambió el editor de posts, antes era sumamente fácil cambiar la URL (permalink)  de un post o página, pero con la nueva versión no encuentro manera de hacerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo cambio el dato en el cuadro `URL` que se ve a la derecha y le doy a actualizar y nada, no se actualiza.

¿Cómo puedo actualizar (cambiar) el valor?

#### Nueva información

No me refiero a cambiar la estructura de los enlaces para que se asignen automáticos. Yo implementé hace años en mi sitio una especie de *convención*  de URLs, para facilitar a un usuario cualquiera pasar de una página a otra cambiando solamente un valor numérico. De ahí que no dejo que WP decide por mí que URL debe llevar un post, sino que asigno yo la URL manualmente. Con esto no hubo nunca problemas hasta ahora.

Una cosa que he visto es que cuando creo un nuevo post, al ponerle el título se activa encima un cuadro para poner la URL que llevaría ese post. Quizá eso resolvería lo que busco para posts nuevos. Pero me encuentro a la vez con otro problema y es que WP no admite caracteres como `_` en la URL que se escribe en ese cuadro. Si escribo este caracter `_`  en alguna parte de la URL, cuando publico el post, lo cambia por `-`. Ese caracter forma parte de la convención de nombrado que he implementando en mi web.

Comment: Segun el source del editor gutemberg el javascript limpia las url con [`cleanForSlug`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/search?q=cleanForSlug&unscoped_q=cleanForSlug) y el [php](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/search?l=PHP&q=slug) pareciera estar llamando a [`sanitize_title`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0.2/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1930) ( mediante `post_slug_meta_box` y `wp_parse_slug_list` ), lo que necesitarías es que llame a [`sanitize_title_with_dashes`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0.2/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1980)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien, creo que he dado con la solución, gracias a [este reporte en GitHub](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/1285).

A partir de la versión 5 Wordpress incorporó un editor llamado Gutenberg.

Este editor cambia varias cosas, entre ellas el permalink del post. En versiones anteriores éste estaba visible todo el tiempo, pero ahora se hace visible solamente cuando se coloca el puntero sobre el título de post.

## 1.

Esta imagen muestra un post en edición, pero sin tener el puntero en el título. Como se puede ver el permalink no aparece por ningún lado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## 2.

Vamos a colocar ahora el puntero sobre el título del post. ¡Sorpresa! El permalink se hace visible y además ¡editable!:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Llegados a este punto, la URL puede modificarse, guardarla (en el input text) pulsando el botón `Guardar` de la derecha y luego actualizarla en el post pulsando el botón azul `Actualizar` que está en la parte superior derecha.

## 3.

**Ahora viene algo rarísimo que antes no ocurría: no acepta caracteres como este `_` en el permalink**. Es más, los que existan al momento de editar se toma la libertad de cambiarlos por `-`.

Probamos a agregar `_notallowed` al final del permalink actual y pulsamos en el botón `Guardar` de la derecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El editor se *toma la libertad*  de modificar mi URL:

- Antes     : `https://www.dominio.com/homilias_tiempo-navidad-ferias-despues-de-la-epifania_dia-12-de-enero/`
- Después: `https://www.dominio.com/homilias-tiempo-navidad-ferias-despues-de-la-epifania-dia-12-de-enero-notallowed/`

Cambió los dos `_` que había en la URL, por `-` y el `_` que intenté poner antes de `notallowed` lo puso como `-`.

---

## Soluciones

En (**2**) ya se mostró la forma de activar el permalink para edición dentro del post. Pero sabiendo que si la URL que queremos lleva caracteres como `_` no funcionará, como se ha expuesto en (**3**).

Si queremos entonces agregar `_` a la URL no nos queda otra (por el momento, espero) que seguir el siguiente procedimiento:

1. En el panel de administración (a la izquierda) ir a `Entradas` y luego a `Todas la entradas`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. En la lista de entradas, seleccionar la que queremos modificar y pulsar en `Edición rápida`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Una vez en `Edición rápida` cambiar la URL (campo `Slug`)  y pulsar en el botón azul `Actualizar` que está en la parte inferior derecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*That's all!*

Espero puede ser útil a alguien que pase por la misma situación.

Answer (score 1):

podes fijarte este plugin Permalinks Customizer.

Te paso el link https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/permalinks-customizer/

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Realmente lo que busco no es personalizar los permalinks. Hace años que tengo una especie de *convención*  de URLs en mi sitio, de forma que los usuarios puedan pasan de una página a otra si lo desearan cambiando solamente una cifra. Eso es así porque el sitio maneja contenido cíclico que cambia según tiempos, semanas, dias .... El problema es que el nuevo editor de WP no me deja cambiar manualmente una URL e incluso no me permite caracteres como `_` en los enlaces. Esos caracteres son parte de mi *convención*  de URLs. Ese es el problema que expongo.